# Error calcular promedio notas JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando calcular el promedio de 4 notas pero no me presenta error, solo que no hace nada, verifiqué todo el código pero no sé cuál es el problema.

Este es el código html con sus inputs:

```
<form role="form">        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>nota 1</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota1" placeholder="ingrese nota1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>nota 2</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota2" placeholder="ingrese nota2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>nota 3</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota3" placeholder="ingrese nota3">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>nota 4</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota4" placeholder="ingrese nota4">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Calcular</button>
    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
             <h3>resultados</h3>
    <input type="number" id="display"value="0" readonly>
```

Y este el código js:

```
window.onload = function init() {
var nota1 = document.getElementById('nota1').value;
var nota2 = document.getElementById('nota2').value;
var nota3 = document.getElementById('nota3').value;
var nota4 = document.getElementById('nota4').value;
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var display = document.getElementById('display');
btn.addEventListener('click', promedio, false);
}

function promedio() {
    var cal = (parseFloat(nota1) + parseFloat(nota2) + parseFloat(nota3) + parseFloat(nota4)) / 4;
    display.innerHTML = cal;
}
```

No me muestra ningún error.

Comment: Hola, prueba en lugar de `display.innerHTML = cal;` pon `display.value = cal;` ya que es un input.

Comment: No me funciona, se eliminar el 0 que tengo como valor DEFAULT en display pero no muestra el resultado.

Comment: y no podrías colocar todo el contenido de la función `init` dentro de la función `promedio` y agregarle un `onclick` al button? aunque el problema es muy sencillo seguro te responden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo la solución a continuación

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 1</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota1" placeholder="ingrese nota1">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 2</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota2" placeholder="ingrese nota2">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 3</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota3" placeholder="ingrese nota3">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 4</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota4" placeholder="ingrese nota4">
        </div>

        <button type="button" onclick="promedio()" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Calcular</button>
    </form>

    <h3>resultados</h3>
    <input type="number" id="display" value="0" readonly>
</body>

<script>
    function promedio() {
        var nota1 = document.getElementById('nota1').value;
        var nota2 = document.getElementById('nota2').value;
        var nota3 = document.getElementById('nota3').value;
        var nota4 = document.getElementById('nota4').value;
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        var display = document.getElementById('display');

        var cal = (parseFloat(nota1) + parseFloat(nota2) + parseFloat(nota3) + parseFloat(nota4)) / 4;
        display.value = cal;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funcionó.

Comment: Hiciste exactamente lo que comente en la pregunta, al menos agrega una explicación para mejorar la calidad de la respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

**EXPLICACIÓN**

- innerHTML no funciona para modificar el valor de un elemento del DOM de tipo `input`, en su lugar deberás usar `value` para modificar el valor de dicha propiedad.
- Dado que la única funcionalidad que buscas es realizar el cálculo de las notas cuando se desencadena un evento en el botón con id `btn`, entonces mejor:
- Recupera dicho botón y agregale un `listener` en el evento `click`, para que entienda que debe ejecutar algo cuando esa acción ocurra.

Código

```
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    btn.addEventListener("click", function promedio() {
      var nota1 = document.getElementById('nota1').value;
      var nota2 = document.getElementById('nota2').value;
      var nota3 = document.getElementById('nota3').value;
      var nota4 = document.getElementById('nota4').value;
      var display = document.getElementById('display');
      var cal = (parseFloat(nota1) + parseFloat(nota2) + parseFloat(nota3) + parseFloat(nota4)) / 4;
      display.value = cal;
})
```

**EJEMPLO COMPLETO**

```html
    <form role="form">        
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 1</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota1" placeholder="ingrese nota1">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 2</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota2" placeholder="ingrese nota2">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 3</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota3" placeholder="ingrese nota3">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label>nota 4</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="nota4" placeholder="ingrese nota4">
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Calcular</button>
        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <h3>resultados</h3>
        <input type="number" id="display"value="0" readonly>
    
    <script>
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
          btn.addEventListener("click", function promedio() {
            var nota1 = document.getElementById('nota1').value;
            var nota2 = document.getElementById('nota2').value;
            var nota3 = document.getElementById('nota3').value;
            var nota4 = document.getElementById('nota4').value;
            var display = document.getElementById('display');
            var cal = (parseFloat(nota1) + parseFloat(nota2) + parseFloat(nota3) + parseFloat(nota4)) / 4;
            display.value = cal;
        })
    </script>
```

**Referencia**

[Revisa este enlace para conocer todos los atributos que tienen los inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: Gracias por la info amigo, me sirvió mucho de ayuda.